# Display two div's side by side inside <li></li> element

Tags: html, css, jquery-nestable

How can I get the two div's inside the list element (part of an ordered list) to display side by side?

The div's in question are with `class="dd-handle"`and `class="btn-group"`.

I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.4 and Nestable2.js

I've tried the following. In this case, the btn-group displays below the first div.

```html
<li class="dd-item" data-id="id">
                <div class="dd-handle">Section name</div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">
                        <span class="icon icon-dots-three-horizontal"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#myModal" id="myModel" data-toggle="modal" data-reportId="id" data-reportName="name">
                                <span></span>
                                Rename
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#myOtherModal" data-toggle="modal">
                                <span></span>
                                Add New
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
   </li>
```

In this case, the layout and functionality of the Nestable2.js library are completely off.

```html
<li class="dd-item" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content: space-around;" data-id="id">
                    <div class="dd-handle" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">Section name</div>
                    <div class="btn-group" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">
                            <span class="icon icon-dots-three-horizontal"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#myModal" id="myModel" data-toggle="modal" data-reportId="id" data-reportName="name">
                                    <span></span>
                                    Rename
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#myOtherModal" data-toggle="modal">
                                    <span></span>
                                    Add New
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
       </li>
```

Comment: The first option does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `style="display: inline"` or `display: inline-block;`, as blocks have a linebreak built into them by default, and this removes that break.

Comment: This has gotten it closer to how it needs to be than anything else, but there seems to be some conflict with Nestable2 that messes up the out of the box styling with this library.

Comment: You might need to look through Nestable and find the rule to do with those classes that breaks it - I do this quite a lot with frameworks and APIs

Comment: `style="display:inline-block;"` was what put the div's next to each other. I did not find what exactly in the Nestable2 css was causing the styling problem, but what was happening was that the expander button (+/- for when children nodes exist) was getting put in further to the left of where it was normally, causing things to look mucked up. The workaround I found for now was to just remove these buttons (my lists of nodes won't be that long). The lines of code that I commented in the library were 671, 680, 681, shown below:

Comment: `setParent: function(li) {
            //Check if li is an element of itemNodeName type and has children
            if (li.is(this.options.itemNodeName) && li.children(this.options.listNodeName).length) {
                // make sure NOT showing two or more sets data-action buttons
                //li.children('[data-action]').remove();
                //li.prepend($(this.options.expandBtnHTML));
                //li.prepend($(this.options.collapseBtnHTML));
            }
        },`

Comment: I'm glad it looks pretty well sorted, just ask if you need any more help! I'm always happy to offer advice, I'm still a student too!